# Standard deviation of a dataset comprised of triplicates (industrial stack sampling data)

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation

I have 4 triplicate data values. each consist of 3 values, for example, this could be 1:

```
Concentration:
45
78
66
```

These data have a mean of `63` and a st.dev. of `16.7`

Now I have 4 similar triplicates, from multiple tests, for example:

```
test:   a     b     c     d
        45    56    34    67
        78    23    67    34
        66    23    56    23

avg     63    34    52.3  41.3
```

I need the standard deviation of the overall distribution from the 4 triplicates. What is the method to do this?

I could average the 4 concentrations, and determine the pooled variance, but would this not be the estimate of the standard deviation if another triplicate test was conducted and the result was the average value?

I could determine the standard deviation of the 4 values, but this ignores the fact that these values consist of a triplicate set of data.

I need to know what the proper method of determining the standard deviation is.

Comment: Why not just think of it as a sample of size 12 and take the sample standard deviation?

Comment: ^There is a considerable amount of variability in stack testing, therefore to determine a test value a minimum of 3 samples are taken, ie, the triplicates. I believe this variability would result in considerably increasing the standard deviation if it was considered a sample of size 12, rather than using the triplicate values.